# Pentaho_send mail to different groups based on columns

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have a requirement to send mail to different users with list of  based on two columns in DB table (System Owner and System Owner Email)

1. Table will contain columns like ProcessID,SystemOwner,Email
2. Once in every month, Pentaho need to read the Table and group all ProcessID's that belongs to specific system owner and send email .
3. There are more than 300+ system owners and creating Filter rows loop for every system Owner is challenging for 300+ system Owners

Any suggestion to perform the above with looping with creating filter rows and sending mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a solution for you. You can download all ktr & job from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1a04fkKnw8bVE01b4SbwKQv3ZFIOXFl6Q)

The main job name is 'mainJOb.ktr'. You should modify your smtp credentials.